# Nginx IP to Domain Redirect

Tags: nginx

I've got a new server that redirects from all DNS requests to https to the domain name. I was having an issue with redirecting from the IP address and I added `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` below.

Is `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` the correct way to redirect from the IP to the domain?

```
server {
    if ($host = www.example.ext) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 


    if ($host = example.ext) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 


        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name example.ext www.example.ext;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are four HTTP statuses that are generally used with redirections and a lot of developers tend to default to `301`. While this will have the intended effect, it may not always be the best status code to use.

Here are the options:

| Code | Definition | When to Use |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 301 | Moved Permanently | A domain or specific URL *that once was valid* has changed. The browser will cache this redirect and not look up the DNS routing again. |
| 302 | Found | A URL is valid and has been temporarily moved elsewhere. The browser will cache the redirect for a short period (usually minutes) and retry if the URL is used again in the future. |
| 307 | Temporary Redirect | A server is being built/rebuilt and, while the work is being done, visitors should be sent elsewhere. The browser will cache this redirect for a short period (usually minutes) and retry the DNS lookup later. |
| 308 | Permanent Redirect | The requested resource may or may not have existed and traffic should be sent to a new location. The browser will cache this redirect and not look up the DNS routing again. |

For your situation, a `301` is “adequate” but, if visitors were never supposed to interact with your server via the bare IP address, a `308` may be more accurate.

A short rule of thumb:

- The URL *used to be valid*? Use 301/302.
- The URL *has never been valid*? Use 307/308.